# Taylor Series Expansions of Exponential Function

Tags: c, taylor-series

I have to write a program in C, that calculates an expansion of pow(a,x) function. I'm sure that my code is wrong, can someone help me with that?

expansion:

```
1 + x log(a) + 1/2 x^2 log^2(a) + 1/6 x^3 log^3(a) + 1/24 x^4 log^4(a) + 1/120 x^5 log^5(a) +...
```

Without using pow function. The next expression has to be calculated from the previous one.

This is what I managed to came with:

```
double series(double x)
{
int i;
double s,w,x2;
s=x;
w=x;
    for(i=1;i<LWS;i++)
{
    w=(w*x/(i+1))*log10(x);
    s+=w;
}
return s;
}
```

I already have the rest of the code.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 0):

log a only needs to be calculated once. A decent compiler will do this for you, but help it out just in case.

Each term is now 1/ i! * x^i *loga^i

The 1/i! term grows very quickly and means that within a few iterations, unless x is massive, the error will be negligible.

You can keep running factors if you want, if (i factorial) is multiplied by i (make sure it is a double, not an integer), xp (x power) is multipled by x on each interation and the same thing happens to loga.

I can't actually remember to to expand a pow series so I'm just assuming your formula is right. It looks basically correct. We use natural logs (ln in math notation, log in C) which kind of cancel with the factorial term, which is related to e^x.

Comment: Well test it first, printing out the terms. Do they converge to zero very quickly for reasonable values of a and x? If the doesn't produce the right answer, what is it off by? Did you ensure that i factorial is double? In your code, it will evaluate to 0 because stored as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you are doing is: `a^x = e^(x * ln(a))` and then using the Taylor's series expansion of `e`.

You have a few error in your code:

1. Since you are using the expansion of `e`, you need to use natural logarithms (base `e`), rather than logarithms to base `10`.
2. The initial value of `s` outside the loop must be set to `1`. This is because `a^x = 1 when x=0` (if `a != 0`).
3. Outside the loop, `w` must be set to `1`. This is to have a nice set of powers of `x * ln(a)`. Earlier with `w=x`, the power of `x` would be one more than power of `ln(a)`.
4. `i` must loop starting from `i=0`. This is to get the factorials right after making the above change.

So the code becomes:

```
double series(double x)
{
    int i;
    double s,w,x2;
    s=1.0;
    w=1.0;
    for(i=0;i<LWS;i++)
    {
        w=(w*x/(i+1))*log(x);
        s+=w;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that, the formula starting value has to be 1.

Comment: @adrian1337 good to hear that. If you think any of the answers here or elsewhere on the site helped you, don't forget to upvote. Also be sure to accept an answer.